# Service Network Restart

Tags: networking, network-adapter, centos-6

I was configuring the network interface for the servers that are on Centos 6 platform. While editing the ifcfi-eth0 file there is a field "ONBOOT" which is set to "yes" if we want that the network interface is up when the server is restarted as per description of Centos documentation.

What i observed that if set ONBOOT to no and give "service network restart"  command the interface is not up. But if I set ONBOOT to yes then the same command brings the network interface up.

What I want to ask is that :

- First Question is that 'Restarting the server has the same effect on NIC card as "service network restart"  command'.
- and second is that 'Is it possible to that a service can reset the hardware similar like reboot the hardware ?'

Thanks

Comment: Although software can invoke hardware reset, the effect is not always the same as powering off. Even rebooting does not necessarily reset hardware fully if you do not power off completely. This is because of poor hardware design and most cards do not have this problem. I experienced it a couple of years ago on a dual-boot system, when Windows drivers could not initialise a card properly after it had been run with Linux, until I powered off completely.

Comment: @AFH **Sir !!!! that means our current hardware is behaving like this means restarting the service is resetting the hardware (i.e. going through the power cycle.). Please confirm sir so that I will be sure next time while configuring the network.**

Comment: My point is that hardware reset is not the same as power-on preset, though in properly designed hardware the effect should be the same. I don't know whether a hardware reset is performed on restarting the service: you would need to look through the sources to find that out, and you would also need a detailed interface specification to understand the commands that are being sent by the driver - not a task to be undertaken lightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singh.

I don't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish, but if you just want to restart all your NICs, then, yes, it is the same.

Among some other things, the "service network restart" script shuts down all your NICs and then starts them up again, just like what happens to them when a server reboots.

I advise you to be carefull if you are planning to do this on a HA cluster, since restarting the NICs may indicate to the other elements of the cluster that the quorum has changed and start migration processes.

Hope it helped.

Comment: **sir!!! I was creating a unified network for super computer in order to give the access to the user out side of cdac (My employer). but when the user restart the service the network connectivity is lost if onboot was not thats why I was asking that restartt was equivalentto NIC shutdown and start after that like system power cycle.**